# Rust error[E0716]: temporary value dropped while borrowed

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I had been [to this question](https://doc.rust-lang.org/error_codes/E0716.html) earlier because the question and the answer(s) were very useful. Yet, my case seems to be somewhat different. Hence, this post:

Because this example (and the accompanying solution/explanation) are very similar to my case, I thought of adding it here (instead of asking a new question).

I am simply trying to read the entries of a directory (Ubuntu Linux 22.10, ext4 filesystem):

```
    let mut all_chosenfiles: Vec<&str> = Vec::new();
    for next_path in path_components {
        for next_dir_entry in fs::read_dir(next_path) {
            for next_file in next_dir_entry {
                let file_metadata = next_file.as_ref().unwrap().metadata().unwrap();
                if file_metadata.is_file()
                    && file_metadata.mode() & 0o500 == 0o500 {
                        let chosen_file = next_file.unwrap().path();
                        all_chosenfiles.push(chosen_file.to_owned().to_str().unwrap());
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Not very idiomatic, I agree, but it serves the purpose at hand.

The compiler is not happy though:

```
error[E0716]: temporary value dropped while borrowed
  --> src/main.rs:31:46
   |
31 |                         all_chosenfiles.push(chosen_file.to_owned().to_str().unwrap());
   |                         ---------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-------------------- temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
   |                         |                    |
   |                         |                    creates a temporary which is freed while still in use
   |                         borrow later used here
   |
   = note: consider using a `let` binding to create a longer lived value
```

I understand what is she complaining about. I have tried to pacify her, by using `let` as has been prescribed [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/error_codes/E0716.html):

```
    for next_path in path_components {
        for next_dir_entry in fs::read_dir(next_path) {
            for next_file in next_dir_entry {
                let file_metadata = next_file.as_ref().unwrap().metadata().unwrap();
                if file_metadata.is_file()
                    && file_metadata.mode() & 0o500 == 0o500 {
                        let chosen_path = next_file.unwrap().path();
                        let chosen_file = &chosen_path.to_owned().to_str().unwrap();
                        all_chosenfiles.push(chosen_file);
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

She is stubborn:

```
error[E0716]: temporary value dropped while borrowed
  --> src/main.rs:31:44
   |
31 |                         let chosen_file = &chosen_path.to_owned().to_str().unwrap();
   |                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                  - temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
   |                                            |
   |                                            creates a temporary which is freed while still in use
32 |                         all_chosenfiles.push(chosen_file);
   |                                              ----------- borrow later used here
   |
   = note: consider using a `let` binding to create a longer lived value
```

I am scratching my head. I am missing some idiom, I am sure.

Is a derefencing using '*' operator (viz., `*chosent_file`) the only way out?

Comment: Your "update" should be an answer instead. That's the way to go, store the owned value. Especially when you don't fully understand lifetimes and ownership yet treat references as something very temporary and local, also be on the lookout for borrows that happen silently through use of a method.

Comment: Following the first part of your advice, I have added my own answer. You are right there. I should have done it myself. Thanks. However, the second part is not clear to me at all, I am afraid.

Answer (score 0):

I have *gotten around*, for the time being, by:

```
let mut all_chosenfiles: Vec<String> = Vec::new(); // of String, and not of &str
    for next_path in path_components {
        for next_dir_entry in fs::read_dir(next_path) {
            for next_file in next_dir_entry {

                let file_metadata = next_file.as_ref().unwrap().metadata().unwrap();
                if file_metadata.is_file()
                    && file_metadata.mode() & 0o500 == 0o500 {
                        // Using as_ref() before unwrapping
                        let chosen_path: PathBuf = next_file.as_ref().unwrap().path();
                        // Doc says that, to_str()
                        // "Yields a &str slice if the Path is valid unicode"
                        let chosen_file: Option<&str> = chosen_path.to_str();
                        // Explicitly owning a String, made out of &str, below!
                        all_chosenfiles.push(chosen_file.unwrap().to_owned());
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Honestly, I am not really sure why it is working. By calling `next_file.as_ref()`, I ensure that a reference to that memory is held. But, how does that solve the problem of `temporary which is freed etc.` issue? Moreover, cloning the *pathstring*s by using `to_str()` seems to be wasteful to me.

Help me fill in, the gaps in my understanding!

Comment: If you want to avoid the cloning and still get an owned `String`, you can do `chosen_path.into_os_string().into_string().unwrap()`.